# Ubuntu 20.04 won't go full screen on Virtualbox with macOS as host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've just installed ubuntu desktop 20.04 on my virtual box on macOS 10.14.6

I installed the guest additions too and restarted.

If I try resizing the window to be smaller it seems that the resolution is updated correctly, if I resize the window to bigger the ubuntu display becomes all black

if I hit cmd+f the VM goes full screen, but the resolution doesn't change from the one in the window. So it remains black if it was a big window, or tiny if it was a small window.

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Just a thought (as I am using a prior Ubuntu version in VMware), go to Ubuntu Startup Application preferences and make sure the Guest Additions have been started.

Comment: hello, thanks, startup application would be the 9 square dots at bottom left? I don't see any guest additions related anything there. but if I do `ps aux|grep VBoxClient` there's a bunch of processes running, so I guess it's up?

Comment: Thank you for your update. The other thing to consider is that Ubuntu V20 is very new and Virtual Box may need an upgrade to keep up.

Comment: I activated the bidirectional sharing of clipboard, and the clipboard looks like being shared, so I guess it's up, guess again, with more confidence.

Comment: yeah, I worried so, I'll try again with the previous LTS.. thanks

Comment: Installed 18.04.4, but it's still not scaling, and I still have the big black frame when in full screen, I guess it's a bit better now, because in window I can get to some bigger resolutions, but it's still not very usable.

Comment: That is very strange. I have V18.04 here (VMware) and all well, and I have seen members here with Virtual Box and V18.04 and all well. I will keep a look out on your behalf.

Comment: I probably managed to get something I can see on my VM display, there's a setting in virtual box (bottom right, for the display): scale to 200% autoscaled output, with that checked in I have a good font dimension and all seems to work

Comment: If I post my answer about this, would you acknowledge it?

Comment: sure, I'm not sure that I got the proper solution or it's just a workaround though

Comment: Virtualbox has not support PPA for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa. check here http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to consider here is that Ubuntu V20 is very new and Virtual Box may need an upgrade to keep up.

Use the older but LTS version of Ubuntu and that should be able to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since perhaps VirtualBox 6.1.8, after installing the guest additions from the CD image, my XUbuntu 20.04 (with MacBook Pro as host) gets a black screen after logging in.  That occurs when the Scale Factor setting on VBox is 200% (standard setting since VBox 6).  If I change the Scale Factor to 100%, then I can log in to Xubuntu but with a quarter-screen display.  That presents a fortunate situation because it allows me to change the guest additions.  First, I removed the prior GA's by running the script from the CD tailed with "uninstall".  Then, based on [this](https://linuxconfig.org/virtualbox-install-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa), I installed the GA's from Ubuntu's repository, which is now at version 6.1.6.  So finally, everything works as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue inside the Ubuntu VM itself by changing the display resolution setting to 2560x1600 and scaling up to 200%.

Easy fix for an annoying issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Scale Factor` setting on VBox to  200% and increase VRAM to 128mb and you should be able to log in to full screen without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

You already install the extencion pack ?
https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.6.vbox-extpack